# How is file overlap avoided in UNIX/Linux?

Tags: file, unix, io, disk, diskspace

If I create a file and my OS starts that file at some memory address on some disk, but I end up writing so much data to my file that the file descriptor is moved into the disk space of the next file on the same disk, does the OS have a way of protecting the file that I am at risk of overwriting? And if so what does UNIX/Linux do in particular?

Comment: I'm no UNIX expert, but I find this interesting, so have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the OS prevents contents of different files from overlapping by allowing the contents of a file to be stored in *non-contiguous* regions of disk. Growing a file past the free region will simply cause the file to include a non-adjacent region of disk. When the disk is sufficiently full, this causes the infamous [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation).

Note that user-space code is never allowed to directly access on-disk addresses of file contents. The file descriptor offset as returned by `lseek` is not an on-disk address, but a virtual offset that the OS can translated to the actual address. The fact that addresses are hidden from user code means that file contents may also be moved to other locations on disk to optimize storage.

Read up on [filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) for more information on this topic.